# How to communication with old robotic arms from NakkaNippon Electric?

Tags: robotic-arm

I have a few robotic manipulators from NakkaNippon Electric and I'm trying to communicate with them using RS232 without success. The robot model are microrobots 88-4 or 88-5.

I'm sending commands via COM port, but I can't received anything from the box. I'm using a USB-to-DB9 converter (FTDI) with a DB9-DB25 cable.

On the net, the only reference I have for the robot is from an old post from year 2000 that was from user @peterkneale.

If it can help, [here is the link to the scanned PDF manual](http://techinfoshawinigan.com/files/).

You can see the commands on page 23-24 of the pdf (page 21-22 in document).

Any advice would be grateful

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturers?

Comment: Have you tried different COM port settings (baud,stop bits,parity)?

Comment: p20 says it's 1200/8/N/1 (with a jumper to change baudrate).

Comment: @Octopus, yes i have tried with the default baudrate. There's also something about DTR (or similar acronym).

Comment: @Paul, I haven't found anything related to the manufacturer on the web. The robots just seem to old.

Comment: "something about DTR" is significant with RS232.  One device is Data Terminal, the other is Data Set.  You might need to use a crossover cable to get the wiring correct.  If you're lucky you could use a null modem cable, but since they mention DTR you probably need a full crossover cable.  If the robot is DTR your side should be DSR, and vice versa.  This site shows you pinouts and data flow control:  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-19.html

Comment: If you look at page 9 of the PDF I linked, the pinouts are shown. I do have a db9-db25 cable. I must confess that my understanding of the electronic world is quite limited for now.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* NickB, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it is a good idea to include details of what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see & what you actually saw. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, on stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).